# FCM notifications not received when phone enters deep sleep

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with FCM functionality. When the phone is awake everything is working (notifications are received when the app is in foreground, background or even if the app is dead).

The problem starts when the phone is entering deep sleep.

As I remember wakelocks are not mandatory with FCM.

I'm pushing "data" type notification with "priority":"high" which should wake up the device.

Problem is that notifications will be received when the phone will awake.

```
public class FCMCallbackService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCMCallbackService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FCMInitializationService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        ...

    }
}
```

In manifest:

```
<service android:name="gcmpush.FCMInitializationService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name="gcmpush.FCMCallbackService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

How can I wake application using push if the phone is sleeping? What is missing?

BDW - if I'm connected to WiFi and phone will go to sleep, but the application is not working - will it use WiFi to receive push? FCM can start the dead application. But if the app is dead, WiFi lock is not acquired. Can in such case device communicate with FCM Server?

Comment: What im missing? Check for FCM Messages Types.

Comment: Can you post your JSON data which you are sending from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following message will not call your onMessageReceived() when your app is in the background or killed, and you can't customize your notification.

```
{
   "to": "/topics/journal",
   "notification": {
   "title" : "title",
   "text": "data!",
   "icon": "ic_notification"
    }
}
```

but instead using this will work

```
{
  "to": "/topics/dev_journal",
   "data": {
       "text":"text",
       "title":"",
       "line1":"Journal",
       "line2":"some data"
   }
}
```

See ref link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795553/2462531)

Comment: Thanks, my bad. FCM console can send only notification messages. 

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: Accept my answer if it is really helps you. :) ;)